# Highcharts - removing a segment from a pie chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am going round in circles a bit with highcharts trying to make a chart as follows:

[image]

And here is a jsbin of the above example:
http://jsbin.com/pezufeweki/1/

My main issue is I have to use a fake segment (and make it white) for the values to be correct (which in turn means the 'hidden' section still has a tooltip.

Is there a way in highcharts to make a segment 'hidden' from the pie chart?

Alternatively, I can get away with making it white but then I would need to hide the tool tip just for that segment as I need it everywhere else.

An added bonus would be for the inner (red) area to start anti-clockwise.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://jsbin.com/zeyaredesa/1/edit?html,js,output ?

Comment: Im afraid that is only option, becuase defaulty highcharts equal value to "whole circle".

Comment: @Adi Please, strongly consider posting the fix as an answer and accept it as the correct one. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed hiding the tooltip per item

```
formatter: function() {
                if (this.key === "hide") {                    
                    return false;
                }
                else return this.y;
            }


{
                    name: 'hide',
                    y: 12,
                    color:'red'
                },
```